# Contact Form 7 textbox height

Tags: contact-form-7

What should I do to align the bottom of my content box with the email text on the left-hand side?
The only option that comes in my mind is to reduce the height of the **text-box of the contact form**, unfortunately I didn't manage to find out a way to do it. Could someone suggest a way to reduce its height?

[picture of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWJ31.jpg)
[image]

[link to the webpage the form is at the bottom](http://proaccount.bg/#contact)